# Concatenating integer values in MIPS

Tags: concatenation, mips

I need to code, in MIPS assembly, something that will take the values of 32-bit integers out of a given array, *concatenate* them instead of adding them, and then store to a variable x.

For example, if Data[1] contained 6, Data[2] contained 9 and Data[3] contained 3, I would need to form the integer 693 and then save it to variable x.

The Java equivalent would be:

```
x = Data[1] + “” + Data[2] + “” + Data[3];
```

And here's what I've got for the assembly code so far:

```
# load root addresses of variable and array
la $s0, x              # load address of variable x into register $s0
la $s1, Data           # load address of ‘Data’ array into $s1

# load contents of array into registers
lw $t0, 4($s1)      # load contents of Data[1] into register $t0 
lw $t1, 4($s1)      # load contents of Data[2] into register $t1
lw $t2, 4($s1)      # load contents of Data[3] into register $t2

# concatenate strings by treating numbers as logic
ori $t3, $zero, $t0  # (I know this is wrong)
???

# store concatenated value into variable
sw $s0, 0($__)      # store value of $__ into register of x
```

How would I go about doing this? I'm extremely puzzled because there does not seem to be a way to concatenate integer values. Am I missing something with how ori is used?

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: _"`x = Data[1] + “” + Data[2] + “” + Data[3];`"_ That looks like it would give you the _string_ `"693"`, whereas in your description you say that you want the _integer_ 693. I think you need to clarify this point.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code concatenates strings. If you want to convert decimal 6, 9 and 3 to decimal 693, try this Java:

```
int[] data = new int[]{6, 9, 3};
int result = data[0] * 100 + data[1] * 10 + data[2] * 1;  // result = 693
```

That should be easy to translate into assembler.

Comment: I was completely approaching this the wrong way. You're right, I would have had a string, not integer, at the end of my code. Thank you and Michael for pointing that out!